# Laravel : how to get the list of element by the parent's parent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 layers of model relationships
the Grandparent Class

```
class GrandParent extends Model
    {
        protected $guarded = [];


        public function parents()
        {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Parent');
        } 
        public function childs()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Childs', 'App\Parent');
        }
     }
```

the parent Class

```
class Parent extends Model
    {

         public function grandParent() {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\GrandParent', 'grandParent_id', 'id');
         }
         public function child()
         {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Child');
         } 
    }
```

The child class

```
class Child extends Model
{

    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Parent', 'parent_id', 'id');
       }
}
```

i want to get list of Child by the grandParent ID

There is any way to get the list by simple Query 
i am  using laravel 5.5
thanks.

Comment: How about `$childs = Grandparent::with('childs')->find($id)->childs`?

Comment: It should only `Parent<--->Child` not `Grandparent` or `GrandChild`. Because `parent`'s `parent` would be `grandparent`

Comment: yes It's works Thanks @devk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the grandparent_id and user_id from the user_table like below.

```
public function childs()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Childs', 'App\Parent','grandparent_id','parent_id','id','id');
}
```

**In your Controller file.**

```
$data = Grandparent::find($grandparent_id)->childs;
```